# Question on Proof of Schwarz Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading the proof of Schwarz Lemma [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Proof).

After we get $\forall r\in(0,1), \forall z\in D_r=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|\leq r\}, |g(z)|\leq |g(z_r)|$ for some $z_r\in \partial D_r$ the proof simply take $r\to 1$ and claim $\forall z\in \{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}, |g(z)|\leq 1$.

I am not comfortable with this limit operation. If this is valid, can we also conclude $\forall z\in \{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|\leq 1\}, |g(z)|\leq 1$ if $g$ is defined on $|z|=1$?

I understand that if $a\in \mathbb{R},\forall t>1,a<t$, then $a\leq \lim\limits_{t\to 1}t=1$. In my head I convince myself of this limit operation using proof by contradiction. So I also attempt to use proof by contradiction for the case in Schwarz Lemma. However, I didn't seem to get any contradiction. Also in this simple example, the variable $t$ only shows up in one place whereas in the Schwarz Lemma, $r$ also appear in the domain where the inequality holds.

Can anyone explain to me how this limit operation is justified? And in general if we have a statement $P(r)$ true for $\forall r<1$, do we also know $P\left(\lim\limits_{r\to 1}r\right)$ is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for every $r<1$ and $|z| < r$, $|g(z)| \le 1/r$ then for $|z| < 1, |g(z)| \le 1$ (proof : assume $|g(z)| > 1$ you'll find an obvious contradiction)

If for every $n$ you know $C \le a_n$ then $C \le \inf_n a_n$. This is specific to $\le$ and $\inf$, due to the way they are defined.

If also $g$ is continuous on $|z| \le 1$ then for $|w|=1$, $g(w) = \lim_{r \to 1} g(wr)$ so $\forall r <1, |g(wr)| \le 1$ implies $|g(w)| \le \sup_r |g(wr)| \le 1$ (again specific to the way $\lim, \le$ and $\sup$ are defined)

Comment: What about on the closed ball? If g is indeed defined on the boundary of the unit ball, can we extend the conclusion to the closed unit ball?

Comment: @FluffySkye continuous not only defined. Usually for $g$ analytic on $|z| < 1$ we define $g|_{|z|=1}$ as $\lim_{r\to 1} g(r.)|_{|z|=1}$ the limit being in general in the sense of distributions (the obtained distribution can be plugged in the Cauchy integral formula) but if $g$ is bounded then the limit can be taken in $L^2$.

Comment: I don't understand. Taking $r\to 1$ solely relies on the fact that the inequality holds for all $r<1$ and irrelavent of whether $g$ is continuous or not right? Following wikipedia, if we use the closed ball as the domain for individual $r$, why can't we claim the result for closed unit ball as long as $g$ is defined?

Comment: Try with $g(z) = 0$ for every $z\in \mathbb{C}$ except $g(1) = 10$. So please complete my answer with the mentioned obvious contradiction if $|g(z)| > 1$ for some $|z| < 1$

Comment: Ok I see your point. But I don't understand what happened lol. Why for open ball it's ok to take limits and for closed ball it's not? Where did we use continuity?

Comment: Yes I have completed the proof by contradiction. Suppose $|g(w)|>1$, take $r=\max\{(\frac{1}{|g(w)|}+1)/2,|w|\}$, then we get a contradiction. In my first attempt I simply take $r=\max\{\frac{1}{|g(w)|},|w|\}$ so I didn't find any contradiction.

Comment: As you see the contradiction holds only if $|z| < 1$ (we didn't suppose any restriction on $g(z)$ for $|z|=1$ not even that it is defined)

Comment: If $g$ is continuous on $|z| \le 1$ then the situation is different because then $g(z) = \lim_{r \to 1} g(zr)$ so $\forall r <1, |g(zr)| \le 1$ implies $|g(z)| \le \inf_r |g(zr)| \le 1$

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you! For me, this tiny step has so many details as you mentioned. Does one always have to go through all these to make a "tiny" step? It's so hard.

Comment: I meant $\sup$ sorry ( $\lim \inf$ holds too, that is the $\inf$ of the sequence with arbitrary many terms removed)